# Can combing bent evaporator coil fins damage it?

Tags: repair, air-conditioning

I have recently purchased a new AC. I opened it to clean air filters and found that an entire row of fins were bent. I asked the manufacturer about this and they said that it won't affect the performance or life of the AC.
They say that this is normal and most of their new ACs have their fins bent like this.
I'm thinking of combing them to make them straight again. Will this damage the evaporator coil?

[image: [1]]

[image: [2]]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could follow the manufacturer's advice - they tend to know what they are talking about...

But if you insist on trying to straighten those bent fins, then use something that will not poke a hole in any of the tubes and go gently.

I have done this for similar heat exchangers with that type of fin and it is possible. Also for heat exchangers which have loops of wire, go slowly and carefully.

Comment: Won't it be difficult to clean these bent fins after few months of usage? Wouldn't the dust collected affect the performance and life of the product in the long run?

Comment: @M.Tarun but they won’t be bent...

Comment: I'm asking that if I don't straighten them wouldn't it be difficult to clean them? Won't the dust collected between these fins affect performance and life of product?

Comment: @M.Tarun it will depend on how dusty and dirty the environment (your house) is.... If it is very dirty then you will need to clean it more often... I have seen some that have not been cleaned in years (like 10 or more) - just uses more energy...

Comment: We live near a power plant and we get lot of dust into our house. The air filter gets dirty very quickly and we have to clean it once every two weeks. Looks like it'll be better if we straighten them. I bought this AC because it's the most power efficient AC in our country. It wouldn't be worth the money if it uses more energy because of some bent fins.

Comment: It may be that the direction of the airflow means that those bent fins are not relevant anyway...

Comment: Maybe. I'll try asking the manufacturer for a replacement under warranty and if that doesn't work out I'll try to comb them myself.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal and trivial damage from handling. Unless it significantly disrupts airflow, it won't harm the performance of the unit by any meaningful amount.

The manufacturer could put guards and ducting around these coils, however that would make the air conditioner more expensive.  Was price a factor in your choice?   If that is, then **they had to hit that price point** or you would not have bought the unit.  So they cut corners on unimportant condenser shielding *instead of* cutting corners on compressor bearings.

Comment: This is one of the most expensive Air conditioners available in our country. It's kind of expensive than other brands for the features it offers. I bought it thinking that their products are of better quality.

Comment: @M.Tarun that’s marketing for you...

Comment: @M.Tarun Bent fins might not be the best measure of quality.  As Harper points out, if they are spending the money on quality internal components when the competition does not, you are still getting your money's worth.

Comment: Also, you can't go by price anymore.  Our friends from a certain far-east country have learned to stick local-friendly brand names on their junk and charge premium prices for it.  It's getting to where you can't buy *cheap* Cheese anymore...